# How does ReentrantLock.tryLock() works as it seems from source code that it does not use synchronized block or function

Tags: java, multithreading, nonblocking, reentrantlock

As I was using `tryLock()` method in one of my project, while using the same the question which is striking mind is that - `tryLock()` is said to be non blocking mechanism, how does it manages to get a lock without blocking.

There can be two scenario

1. It is not using `synchronized` block/method internally, then the question is, how does it work in multi threaded environment
2. It is using `synchronized` block/method internally, then the question is, how is it non blocking

In order to find the answer I have checked the below code for `tryLock`

```
public boolean tryLock() {
    return sync.nonfairTryAcquire(1);
}
```

And here goes the code for `sync.nonfairTryAcquire(1)` which actually gets the work done

```
 final boolean nonfairTryAcquire(int acquires) {
        final Thread current = Thread.currentThread();
        int c = getState();
        if (c == 0) {
            if (compareAndSetState(0, acquires)) {
                setExclusiveOwnerThread(current);
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if (current == getExclusiveOwnerThread()) {
            int nextc = c + acquires;
            if (nextc < 0) // overflow
                throw new Error("Maximum lock count exceeded");
            setState(nextc);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

As it seems that the code for `tryLock()` does not use `synchronized` anywhere, **how does it work in multi threaded environment?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how does it manages to get a lock without blocking?

It *doesn't* always get the lock. That's the whole point: `lock.tryLock()` can fail when `lock.lock()` would have blocked the caller.

> it does not use synchronized block or function

That would defeat the purpose. The point is *not* to block for any reason.

I am not familiar with that code, but it looks like the lock actually is acquired (or not) in `compareAndSetState(0, acquires)`.  Probably there is a [Compare and Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) hardware instruction somewhere at the heart of it.

FWIW, The [AtomicInteger.compareAndSet(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet-int-int-) function does something very similar.